# Why is my checkbox in my recycler view not getting clicked?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I have a recycler view, in which I have a cardview which also holds a textview and checkbox. 
I have onItemTouchListener for Recyclerview:

```
lvPosts.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```

and for the checkbox I have it as follows in the view holder:

```
holder.cbSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            }
        });
```

The propblem is when I click on the checkbox, the onClick of the item gets triggered. But when I keep the checkbox pressed for sometime it works.
I have no idea why is it behaving this weird.

Please help.

Checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/cbSelected"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"

    />
```

Comment: hi, did you able to solve the prob? im having the same issues here.

Comment: Can you add the source of the RecyclerItemClickListener class? Solution is probably in there because it intercepts the touch events.